# Confused about how get value from DictionaryList at specific index

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a DictionaryList to keep some values coming from an xml file

this is the my xml file

```
<DnsServers>
  <Dns>
    <Name>Google</Name>
    <Value>8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4</Value>
  </Dns>
  <Dns>
    <Name>Telekom</Name>
    <Value>195.175.39.39,195.175.39.40</Value>
  </Dns>
</DnsServers>
```

and then populating a combobax  just key values like this way .

```
void ReadFromDnsServerList()
 {

        _nameValueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //var list = new List<string>();


        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("DnsServerList.xml");
        if (doc.Root != null)
        {
            var keyValueXml = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("Dns")
                select new
                {
                    name = c.Element("Name").Value,
                    value = c.Element("Value").Value
                };
            foreach (var info in keyValueXml)
            {
                _nameValueDictionary.Add(info.name,info.value);

            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in _nameValueDictionary)
            {
                cmbDns.Items.Add(item.Key);
            } 

    }

}
```

I am wondering that How can I  get  corresponding dns value inside cmbDns_SelectedIndexChanged 
change event  somethinglike this

```
name=Google   value =8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Try this: `cmbDns.DisplayMember = "Key";` `cmbDns.ValueMember = "Value";` and `cmbDns.DataSource =  _nameValueDictionary;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void ReadFromDnsServerList()
{
    _nameValueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("DnsServerList.xml");
    if (doc.Root != null)
    {
        var keyValueXml = from c in doc.Root.Descendants("Dns")
            select new
            {
                name = c.Element("Name").Value,
                value = c.Element("Value").Value
            };
        foreach (var info in keyValueXml)
        {
            _nameValueDictionary.Add(info.name, info.value);
        }

        cmbDns.DisplayMember = "Key";
        cmbDns.ValueMember = "Value";
        cmbDns.DataSource = _nameValueDictionary.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.